# Semantic Segmentation to Bounding Boxes

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, computer-vision

Suppose you are performing semantic segmentation. For simplicity, let's assume this is 1D segmentation rather than 2D (i.e. we only care about finding objects with width).

So the desired output of our model might be something like:

```
[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1], # label channel 1 
    [1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1], # label channel 2 
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], # label channel 3
    #...
]
```

However, our trained imperfect model might be more like

```
[
    [0.1,  0.1,  0.1,  0.4,  0.91, 0.81, 0.84], # label channel 1 
    [0.81, 0.79, 0.85, 0.1,  0.2,  0.61, 0.91], # label channel 2 
    [0.3,  0.1,  0.24, 0.87, 0.62, 1,    0   ], # label channel 3
    #...
]
```

What would be a performant way, using python, for getting the boundaries of the labels (or bounding box)

e.g. (zero-indexed)

```
[
    [[4, 6]],        # "objects" of label 1
    [[0, 2], [5, 6]] # "objects" of label 2
    [[3, 5]],        # "objects" of label 3
]
```

if it helps, perhaps transforming it to a binary mask would be of more use?

```
def binarize(arr, cutoff=0.5):
  return (arr > cutoff).astype(int)
```

with a binary mask we just need to find the consecutive integers of the indices of nonzero values:

def consecutive(data, stepsize=1):
    return np.split(data, np.where(np.diff(data) != stepsize)[0]+1)

find "runs" of labels:

```
def binary_boundaries(labels, cutoff=0.5):  
  return [consecutive(channel.nonzero()[0]) for channel in binarize(labels, cutoff)]
```

name objects according to channel name:

```
def binary_objects(labels, cutoff=0.5, channel_names=None):
  if channel_names == None: 
    channel_names = ['channel {}'.format(i) for i in range(labels.shape[0])]

  return dict(zip(channel_names, binary_boundaries(labels, cutoff)))
```

Comment: Your question is not clear but if you are asking how to compute the bounding box from segmentation image, follow my answer.

Comment: @NoumanRiazKhan I appreciate your time and input. What part of my question is not clear? This is not quite bounding boxes as it is in 1D... so 1. the labels' dimension as well as the output would have to be reformatted and  2. I was hoping for something a bit more sophisticated than a binary mask, (e.g. if a channel was `[0, 1, 0.6, 1, 1, 1]` then adjust 0.6 according to its neighbors...

Comment: DId you try the solution I proposed?
The unclear part is, do you want to have index of all non-zero values for every label or do you want 4 bounding box points?
Do you need to find optimal cut off point?

Comment: @NoumanRiazKhan I just tried your solution, however that entire module is centered around 3-channel images and so not ideal in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your trained model returned the `float image` and not the `int image` you were looking for (and it's not 'imperfect' if decimals were bothering you) and Yes! you do need to `threshold` it to get `binary image`.

Once you do have the binary image, lets do some work with `skimage`.

```
label_mask = measure.label(mask)
props = measure.regionprops(label_mask)
```

mask is your binary image and here you do have `props` the properties of all the regions which are detected objects actually.

Among these properties, there exists bounding box!